# How to shuffle data in python keeping some n number of rows intact

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to shuffle my data in such manner that each 4 rows remain intact. For example I have 16 rows then first 4 rows can go to last and then second four rows may go to third  and so on in any particular order. I am trying to do thins in python

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?  Some examples of input and output would be useful too.

Comment: I am not getting any function to do this sort of shuffling
For example, if my input has 100 rows then I want it to get shuffled in such a manner that first 4 rows take any place, and then next 4 take some other place and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape splitting the first axis into two with the later of length same as the group length = `4`, giving us a `3D` array and then use [`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html), which shuffles along the first axis. The reshaped version being a view into the original array, assigns back the results directly into it. Being `in-situ`, this should be pretty efficient (both memory-wise and on performance).

Hence, the implementation would be as simple as this -

```
def array_shuffle(a, n=4):
    a3D = a.reshape(a.shape[0]//n,n,-1) # a is input array
    np.random.shuffle(a3D)
```

Another variant of it would be to generate random permutations covering the length of the `3D` array, then indexing into it with those and finally reshaping back to `2D`.This makes a copy, but seems more performant than `in-situ` edits as shown in the previous method.

The implementation would be -

```
def array_permuted_indexing(a, n=4):
    m = a.shape[0]//n
    a3D = a.reshape(m, n, -1)
    return a3D[np.random.permutation(m)].reshape(-1,a3D.shape[-1])
```

Step-by-step run on shuffling method -

1] Setup random input array and split into a 3D version :

```
In [2]: np.random.seed(0)

In [3]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(16,3))

In [4]: a3D = a.reshape(a.shape[0]//4,4,-1)

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[55, 58, 75],
       [78, 78, 20],
       [94, 32, 47],
       [98, 81, 23],
       [69, 76, 50],
       [98, 57, 92],
       [48, 36, 88],
       [83, 20, 31],
       [91, 80, 90],
       [58, 75, 93],
       [60, 40, 30],
       [30, 25, 50],
       [43, 76, 20],
       [68, 43, 42],
       [85, 34, 46],
       [86, 66, 39]])
```

2] Check the 3D array :

```
In [6]: a3D
Out[6]: 
array([[[55, 58, 75],
        [78, 78, 20],
        [94, 32, 47],
        [98, 81, 23]],

       [[69, 76, 50],
        [98, 57, 92],
        [48, 36, 88],
        [83, 20, 31]],

       [[91, 80, 90],
        [58, 75, 93],
        [60, 40, 30],
        [30, 25, 50]],

       [[43, 76, 20],
        [68, 43, 42],
        [85, 34, 46],
        [86, 66, 39]]])
```

3] Shuffle it along the first axis (in-situ) :

```
In [7]: np.random.shuffle(a3D)

In [8]: a3D
Out[8]: 
array([[[69, 76, 50],
        [98, 57, 92],
        [48, 36, 88],
        [83, 20, 31]],

       [[43, 76, 20],
        [68, 43, 42],
        [85, 34, 46],
        [86, 66, 39]],

       [[55, 58, 75],
        [78, 78, 20],
        [94, 32, 47],
        [98, 81, 23]],

       [[91, 80, 90],
        [58, 75, 93],
        [60, 40, 30],
        [30, 25, 50]]])
```

4] Verify the changes back in the original array :

```
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[69, 76, 50],
       [98, 57, 92],
       [48, 36, 88],
       [83, 20, 31],
       [43, 76, 20],
       [68, 43, 42],
       [85, 34, 46],
       [86, 66, 39],
       [55, 58, 75],
       [78, 78, 20],
       [94, 32, 47],
       [98, 81, 23],
       [91, 80, 90],
       [58, 75, 93],
       [60, 40, 30],
       [30, 25, 50]])
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [102]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(16000,3))

In [103]: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# @piRSquared's soln1
In [106]: %timeit df.iloc[np.random.permutation(np.arange(df.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 4)).ravel()]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop

# @piRSquared's soln2
In [107]: %%timeit
     ...: d = df.set_index(np.arange(len(df)) // 4, append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
     ...: pd.concat([d.xs(i) for i in np.random.permutation(range(4))])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.48 ms per loop

# Array based soln-1
In [108]: %timeit array_shuffle(a, n=4)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.38 ms per loop

# Array based soln-2
In [109]: %timeit array_permuted_indexing(a, n=4)
10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop
```

Comment: `This function only shuffles the array along the first axis`... brilliant!

Comment: @Nilesh Don't forget to accept one of the solutions that worked out best for you. Also, you can upvote answers. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: @piRSquared Seems like shuffling wasn't a great choice. Guessing internally its making copying/doing some not-so-performant stuffs. Moved to indexing for much better timings.

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(16, 4)), columns=list('WXYZ'))
df

    W  X  Y  Z
0   9  8  6  2
1   0  9  5  5
2   7  5  9  4
3   7  1  1  8
4   7  7  2  2
5   5  5  0  2
6   9  3  2  7
7   5  7  2  9
8   6  6  2  8
9   0  7  0  8
10  7  5  5  2
11  6  0  9  5
12  9  2  2  2
13  8  8  2  5
14  4  1  5  6
15  1  2  3  9
```

---

**Option 1**
Inspired by @B.M. and @Divakar
I'm using `np.random.permutation` because it returns a copy that is a permuted version of what was passed.  This means I can then pass that directly to `iloc` and return what I need.

```
df.iloc[np.random.permutation(np.arange(16).reshape(-1, 4)).ravel()]

    W  X  Y  Z
12  9  2  2  2
13  8  8  2  5
14  4  1  5  6
15  1  2  3  9
0   9  8  6  2
1   0  9  5  5
2   7  5  9  4
3   7  1  1  8
8   6  6  2  8
9   0  7  0  8
10  7  5  5  2
11  6  0  9  5
4   7  7  2  2
5   5  5  0  2
6   9  3  2  7
7   5  7  2  9
```

---

**Option 2**

I'd add a level to the index that we can call on when shuffling

```
d = df.set_index(np.arange(len(df)) // 4, append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
d

      W  X  Y  Z
0 0   9  8  6  2
  1   0  9  5  5
  2   7  5  9  4
  3   7  1  1  8
1 4   7  7  2  2
  5   5  5  0  2
  6   9  3  2  7
  7   5  7  2  9
2 8   6  6  2  8
  9   0  7  0  8
  10  7  5  5  2
  11  6  0  9  5
3 12  9  2  2  2
  13  8  8  2  5
  14  4  1  5  6
  15  1  2  3  9
```

Then we can shuffle

```
pd.concat([d.xs(i) for i in np.random.permutation(range(4))])

    W  X  Y  Z
12  9  2  2  2
13  8  8  2  5
14  4  1  5  6
15  1  2  3  9
4   7  7  2  2
5   5  5  0  2
6   9  3  2  7
7   5  7  2  9
0   9  8  6  2
1   0  9  5  5
2   7  5  9  4
3   7  1  1  8
8   6  6  2  8
9   0  7  0  8
10  7  5  5  2
11  6  0  9  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code in python does the magic

```
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np
from math import ceil

#creating sample dataset
d=[[i*4 +j for i in range(5)] for j in range(25)]
a = np.array(d, int)
print '--------------Input--------------'
print a

gl=4 #group length i.e number of rows needs to be intact
parts=ceil(1.0*len(a)/gl) #no of partitions based on grouplength for the given dataset

#creating partition list and shuffling it to use later 
x = [i for i in range(int(parts))]
shuffle(x)

#Creates new dataset based on shuffled partition list
fg=x.pop(0)
f = a[gl*fg:gl*(fg+1)]
for i in x: 
 t=a[gl*i:(i+1)*gl]
 f=np.concatenate((f, t), axis=0)
print '--------------Output--------------'
print f
```